# Should I provide layer-specific exceptions in a SpringBoot backed REST Api?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, exception

I have a SpringBoot based REST Api structured as follows :

```
Rest Controller -> Service -> Repository
```

and I'm wondering how exactly to handle exceptions "properly".

For instance, let's say someone calls a /myresources/{id} endpoint with a non-existant {id}. The call gets delegated to the service which in turns tries to get the MyResource from the Repository. It fails and returns null. The Service then throws a MyResourceNotFoundException.

Now I want a specific format for my REST errors so I have a @ControllerAdvice ResponseEntityExceptionHandler which handles the custom serialization of these exceptions (@ExceptionHandler(MyResourceNotFoundException.class)).

Fine.

But this is going to result in a lot of handling/translation for each different custom exception. So I thought I could generify this by adding HttpStatus codes and messages to a base abstract exception class which MyResourceNotFound and others would extend and override. Thus the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler would simply handle building my custom error DTO in a standard way.

But then I realised that I'm adding REST concepts to an exception thrown at the service level. These shouldn't be aware of such notions...

Maybe I should catch the MyResourceNotFoundException in the Controller and throw another layer-specific exception which contains the appropriate messages and HttpStatus etc. in order to handle this generically in the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler...

What are your thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize the exception as XYZMicroserviceException.

```
class XYZGenericException extends Exception{
    String message;
   custom error details....


    XYZgenericException(errorMessage,   custom error Details..){
      this.message=errorMessage;
      .......
  }   
}
```

and you  can surround the suspected call which would lead to exception with try block and raise the generic exception in catch block  that can be handled in global  exception handler.

```
   try{
        xyz.abcMethod() // may give some exception
      }
    catch(Exception e){
    throw new XYZGenericException(.........)
     }



In the exception handler class with @restcontrolleradvice you can annotate the methods with the type of specific exception class to be handled.
```